# One field with many "precisions" for each data type?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have about 50 product types in my `PostgreSQL 9.2.3` database.

Some of them are divisible, some are not.

What makes things more complicated is that `"volume"` of different products should have different precision.

```
Product type 1: allowed 8 decimal places.
Product type 2: only integer values.
Product type 3: 2 decimal places
Product type 4: 2 decimal places
Product type 5: 3 ---- || ------
Product type 6: 4 ---- || ------
Product type 7: 16 ---- || -----
Product type 8: integer values
Product type 9: 4 decimal places
Product type 10: 5 decimal places
Product type 11: 12 decimal places
```

There is also `"orders"` table, one for all products, where almost all columns are
the same (user, contractor, order date, shipping price, etc.). The only exception
is `"volume"` column.

What data type should I use?

I thought about using `"numeric"` field for all product types + storing info about 
precision for every product type and convert values in "orders register" views to 
required precision, but wouldn't it result in data consistency failures?

In this solution there is no way to check if e.g. integer value for 'product type 8'
is integer, I only display it as integer. :(

Another way is to create one column per each data type, e.g. volume_int, volume_num_2, 
volume_num_5, etc, which is really awful. :(

...and another solution is to use table inheritance, like that:

```
orders <- volume is integer
orders_product_1 (inherits orders) <- volume is numeric(24,8)
orders_product_2 (inherits orders) <- volume is integer
orders_product_3 (inherits orders) <- volume is numeric(20,2)
```

...but creating about 20 inherited tables seems like a triumph of form over content...

What would be the best solution? Maybe there is another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NUMERIC` with the greatest scale and precision you will need for any of the values.

If the precisions are quite static and defined by another field in the same table, you can use a `CHECK` constraint or series of constraints to enforce rules about the values.

If the precsions cannot be found without a lookup into another table you will need to use a trigger to enforce the rules instead.

The only alternative I see is to `CREATE TYPE` a composite type that has a value and a units/precison stored alongside it. That seems heavy handed and will be a pain to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go with first solution with numeric field and table with information about precision. In this case you also can change precision later if you need it.
Or you can store all data as integers and store coefficients in some table and calculate your field like `value * coefficient` (which could be 1, 0.01 and so on)